# Question re: TypeScript object property pointers passed into methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I'm fairly new to TypeScript and am trying to create a simple range slider with two handles using D3.js.

I've created a basic class for the slider objects:

```
export class VerticalRangeSlider{
    private sliderContainer:  d3.Selection<SVGGElement, any, HTMLDivElement, any>;
    private scale: d3.ScaleLinear<number, number>;
    
    private sliderTopBound: number;
    private sliderBottomBound: number;

    private handleTopY: number;
    private handleBottomY: number;
    private handleTop: d3.Selection<SVGCircleElement, any, HTMLDivElement, any>;
    private handleBottom: d3.Selection<SVGCircleElement, any, HTMLDivElement, any>;

constructor(slContainer: d3.Selection<SVGGElement, any, HTMLDivElement, any>, scl: d3.ScaleLinear<number, number>){
    this.sliderContainer = slContainer;
    this.scale = scl;

    this.sliderTopBound = 0;
    this.sliderBottomBound = scl.range()[0];
    this.handleTopY = this.sliderTopBound;
    this.handleBottomY = this.sliderBottomBound;

    this.initSlider();
}
```

The two handles are created in the initSlider method. I have an anonymous function called to handle drag events, which calls the moveHandle method to re-render the circles.

Because I've found that *this.* has a different context within an anonymous function, I've declared a variable inside initSlider to hold the pointer to the parent object: `var parentObject = this;`.

```
   this.handleTop = this.sliderContainer.insert("circle", ".track-overlay")
    .attr("class", "handle")
    .attr("r", 9)
    .attr("cy", this.handleTopY)
    .attr("desc", this.handleTopY)
    .call(d3.drag()
    .on('drag', function(){
       parentObject.moveHandle(parentObject.handleTop, parentObject.handleTopY, d3.event.dy, parentObject.sliderTopBound, parentObject.handleBottomY);
    }));

    this.handleBottom = this.sliderContainer.insert("circle", ".track-overlay")
    .attr("class", "handle")
    .attr("r", 9)
    .attr("cy", this.handleBottomY)
    .attr("desc", this.handleBottomY)
    .call(d3.drag()
    .on('drag', function(){
       parentObject.moveHandle(parentObject.handleBottom, parentObject.handleBottomY, d3.event.dy, parentObject.handleTopY, parentObject.sliderBottomBound);
    }));
```

I ran into issues with the moveHandle method:

```
private moveHandle(handle: d3.Selection<SVGCircleElement, any, HTMLDivElement, any>, currentPosition: number, increment: number, topBound: number, bottomBound:number): void {
    
        var legalIncrement: number;
        //upward movement
        if(Math.sign(increment) === -1){
            legalIncrement = increment <= (currentPosition - topBound) ? increment : (currentPosition - topBound);
            console.log("allowed increment: "+legalIncrement);
        }
        //downward movement
        else {
            legalIncrement = increment <= (bottomBound - currentPosition) ? increment : (bottomBound - currentPosition);
            console.log("allowed increment: "+legalIncrement);

        }
        
    if(legalIncrement !== 0){
        currentPosition = (currentPosition + legalIncrement)
        handle.attr("transform", "translate(0," + currentPosition + ")");
    }

}
```

When I tried to drag the circles, they would briefly render as expected but then immediately snap back to their original position.

However, everything worked when I passed a pointer to the parent object into moveHandle directly: `parentObject: VerticalRangeSlider): void {`

`parentObject.handleBottomY = parentObject.handleBottomY + increment; parentObject.handleBottom.attr("cy", parentObject.handleBottomY);`

My original assumption was that I was passing pointers to the properties of my parent object into my method, but it looks like that is not the case. My best theory is that new objects are being created, instead.

I'd really appreciate any insights into this behaviour (as well as any feedback for better structuring my JS/TS code).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you end up needing a reference to the parent. To work around this problem, you can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Description). Functions defined with the `function () {}` form will create their own `this`, so **keeping a reference to the parent `this` is needed** like you did with `parentObject`.

On the other hand, arrow functions (the `=>` form) **do not bind their own `this`**. This means the `this` in an arrow function refers to the parent `this`, and you don't need a reference: you can use `this` directly

We can change the `drag` handler as an arrow function too.

Here's your code with some changes. It may not be entirely correct because I may have missed some meaning: let me know.

```
this.handleTop = this.sliderContainer.insert("circle", ".track-overlay")
  .attr("class", "handle")
  .attr("r", 9)
  .attr("cy", this.handleTopY)
  .attr("desc", this.handleTopY)
  .call(d3.drag()
  .on('drag', () =>
     this.moveHandle(this.handleTop, this.handleTopY, d3.event.dy, this.sliderTopBound, this.handleBottomY);
  );

this.handleBottom = this.sliderContainer.insert("circle", ".track-overlay")
.attr("class", "handle")
.attr("r", 9)
.attr("cy", this.handleBottomY)
.attr("desc", this.handleBottomY)
.call(d3.drag()
.on('drag', () => this.moveHandle(this.handleBottomY, this.handleTopY, d3.event.y, this.sliderBottomBound);
);

private moveHandle = (currentPosition: number, topBound: number, increment:number, bottomBound:number): void => {
        var legalIncrement: number;
        //upward movement
        if(Math.sign(increment) === -1){
            legalIncrement = increment <= (currentPosition - topBound) ? increment : (currentPosition - topBound);
            console.log("allowed increment: "+legalIncrement);
        }
        //downward movement
        else {
            legalIncrement = increment <= (bottomBound - currentPosition) ? increment : (bottomBound - currentPosition);
            console.log("allowed increment: "+legalIncrement);

        }
        
    if(legalIncrement !== 0){
        currentPosition = (currentPosition + legalIncrement)
        this.attr("transform", "translate(0," + currentPosition + ")");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight on the scope of 'this' and arrow functions! That definitely worked.